# Inner if-return should be used by outer if-return

Tags: java

I googled about it but didn't find anything:

So I have 3 checks while the second if check will be checked by two inner if statements, and regarding to the outcome I want to return different integer to the method which will be called at some other place, I couldn't find any explanation on the web if this works, so 1000 should be only returned if none of these condidtions is fulfilled

so my main goal is if I give to this method for str1 "getBack", I want as return 500

```
public int checkValues(String str1, String str2, String str3, String str4) {
    if (str1 == null || str2 == null) {
        return 400;
    }
    if (str1 != null && str2 != null) {
        if (str1.equals("getBack")){
        return 500;
        }
        else { return 600;}
    }
    if (str3 == null && str4 == null) {
        return 700;
    }
    if (str4 == null) {
        return 800;
    }
    return 1000;
}
```

Comment: and what is not happening?

Comment: You could create a JUnit test that checks all your conditions and see if the method performs a you planned.

Comment: no I am just confused if this works, I want to get 500 if str1 equals getBack, but I kinda feel my logic won't work

Comment: right now you will get 500 if str1 equals getBack AND str2 is not null. If you don't care about str2 in that case, you have to make a change. However, we cannot help as long as we do not know what you want to do if str1 is getBack and str2 s null (return 500? then split your "outer" if statement, return 1000 - your code already does that)

Comment: Ok, there is only one problem. If str2 is null and str1 is "getBack", mothod will not return 500. Fix it by yourself !!! ;)

Comment: If `(str1 == null || str2 == null)` is false, `(str1 != null && str2 != null)` is necessarily true and you will never get to check `str3` and `str4`. I'm surprised the compiler didn't warn you about unreachable code.

Comment: Here's what your code does now:
Checks if str1 or str2 is null, if so --> Quits method with 400 return value.
If not, then checks if str1 and str2 are not nulls, if it's true, checks if str1 is equal to getBack. If so --> Quits method with 500 return value, else with 600 return value.
The rest of your code will never run, since we already matched all kind of possible conditions. Your solution might be returning a List instead of one integer, containing all kind of response codes.

Comment: thanks thats exactly what I thought when I looked at it, that I am doing something wrong but I couldn't figure out what, it's like looking into the forest for a tree